# Looking for the source concerning a claim made about Yosef and his brothers

Tags: sources-mekorot, yosef

[Here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/leff/archives/vayeish.htm), HaRav Zev Leff makes the claim that the quarrel between Yosef and his brothers was primarily about the legal or covenantal status of the sons of Israel. The author claims that Yosef’s brothers believed themselves to be already Klal Yisrael, while Yosef, following his father, knew them to be ‘in transition’ from the status of B’nei Noach. Unfortunately no source is provided for this claim, so I was wondering if someone could provide me with one.

Answer (score 7):

This approach seems to have been innovated by [R. Yehuda Rosanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Rosanes) (1657-1727) in the first piece of his [Parashat Derakhim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48331&st=&pgnum=18).

Answer (score 4):

Moshav Zikeinim, a collection of thoughts on the parsha from the *Baalei HaTosafos*, says it ([*parshas Vayeishev* ד"ה ד"א את דבתם](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20791&pgnum=80)). The Riva (Rav Yehudah Ben Eliezer) ([ibid ד"ה ויבא יוסף](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30904&pgnum=71)) hints to it, but the Bartenura ([ibid ד"ה את דבתם](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30904&pgnum=71)) says it straight out.

Comment: Where do they ?

Comment: Please forgive my foolishness: could you translate Mirumaz for me? I don’t have a dictionary to hand.

Comment: @Tom w merumaz meants hints. Meaning he seems to imply it.

Comment: You were right about Moshav zekeinim. I took the liberty of adding the source. However, if you look closely, the bartenura says they both held they were benei Noach. No reason to assume Riva disagrees.

Answer (score 1):

The Malbim [in Eretz Chemdah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38362&st=&pgnum=103) (HebrewBooks link) quotes this idea from Rabbi Eliyahu Mizrachi (1455 - 1525).